# Recursive palindrome checking without using vectors, size or additional parameters

Tags: c++, recursion

The question is simple - palindrome checking. The restrictions complicate it quite a bit:

1. Not allowed to use *any* string functions, or even the string header file (`strlen()`is out).
2. Not allowed to use vectors or iterators.
3. No additional parameters can be passed to the function (this means that solutions which use indexes for start and end cannot be used). This also means that size of the array cannot be passed.
4. Solution should be recursive.

This is the best I could come up with:

```
bool checkPalindrome(char input[]) {
 static int count = 0, i = 0, done = 0;
 while(!done){
    if(input[i]!='\0'){
        // length of string is stored in count
        count++;
        i++;
    }
 }
 done = 1; i = 0;
 if(count>0){
    // check characters from start and end
    if(input[i]==input[count-1]){
        count = count - 2;
        return checkPalindrome(input+1);
    }
    else
        return false;
 }
 else{
    return true;
 }
}
```

But this doesn't work on the online IDE where I'm supposed to submit this. It just throws up a "Time Limit Exceeded" error. Could someone point me towards the right direction?

Comment: what is the expected complexity?

Comment: Time complexity is not specified, but each test case should be finished between 150 and 350 ms (Quite arbitrary, I know). Marks are only deducted if the test case refuses to run, or you take O(nˆ3) complexity, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loop, where you check the length of the string, is an infinite loop.
Done is always set to 0 and never change.
In fact, this flag is not required, you can modify the loop as follows:

```
while (input[i] != '\0') {
        count++;
        i++;
}
```

If you do want to keep the 'done' flag, you just need to set it to 1 if the if clause condition is false:

```
while (!done) {
    if (input[i] != '\0') {
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        done = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: PS - Please delete your duplicate answer. :P